# Why does git reject two pushes in a row?

Tags: git, eclipse

Sometimes when I push changes and then push more changes I see a "rejected, not fast forward" error. I am the only one using the repository so no one else has pushed anything.

It seems to happen when I push several changes quickly, which makes me wonder if it is timing related. Sometimes I push a change and quickly push an amended correction and then I see this problem. It happens infrequently, so I have not been able to observe a repeatable pattern.

I am just confused how git could think the remote has diverged when I am the only one pushing to it? Can anyone clarify the likely causes of this issue?

Thanks

Comment: "rejected, not fast forward" is a message from the server. You might get this e.g. when you amend a commit but the previous commit was already pushed and then pushed the amend commit. Probably everything works as it should. Please show what commits have to pull when you get this message.

Comment: I would avoid the forced push until you understand why this is happening. I only use forced push when I know there's a commit I want to remove from the server, and no one else needs it. It's meant as a careful and deliberate action, not as a work-around for the kind of problem you're describing here.

Comment: My bet is @howlger's theory: this probably happens to you when you amend a commit and push again. It should have nothing to do with timing. When it happens, do a `git fetch` (not `git pull`) and examine the state of your sandbox with `git log --all --graph` to see exactly how the two have diverged, that should explain why the commit is being rejected as not fast-forward.

Comment: Do you amend often? Maybe you forgot you're doing it? Fixing a typo would be a good reason to amend and then push again within a minute.

Comment: Yes, it might have to do with ammended commits, for example fixing a typo. Can't you push an ammded commit?

Comment: An amended commit replaces the previous commit. If you already have pushed the previous commit, you have to force push to override/replace the already pushed commit with the amended commit. But be careful, a force push cannot be undone and if somebody else already got the previous commit, it becomes difficult for that person.

Comment: That is probably the explanation.  I always work in my own branch, with controlled merges to main, so I am not worried about other people pushing to my branch.

Comment: Please amend the question to integrate comments and clarify the problem - one shouldn’t need to read _any_ comments to understand a question :)

Comment: My question was confused because I was confused. If I wasn't confused, I would not have posted my question. Thanks to some great help here, I am no longer confused about this question. I could go back and edit the question to setup the answer but I am not sure if re-writing history is the best  way to be helpful.

Comment: Amending your question to be clearer is not rewriting history - it's making your question useful to future readers :). Comments can be deleted at any time (and should be cleaned up when obsolete), they shouldn't be the only source of relevant information. See [How to ask: Post the question and respond to feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If in doubt I suggest to [read and/or post on https://meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basking-questions%5D+edit+solved). Unclear questions are likely to continue to accumulate downvotes.

Comment: I am open to amending the question to be more helpful. I want to do it in a thoughtful way that accurately presents my original confusion, the solution, and the way people here provided good information.

Comment: I have edited the question in response to the requests. Please let me know if this is more helpful. I've tried to preserve the original context while making it more useful to future readers. I can try again if this does not work.

Comment: Not really :). Adding to the question the commands you were executing would help significantly, and then all these comments can be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments we've now determined this is happening because you are doing a quick fix (perhaps a typo or similar) and amending the previous commit. Once you amend a commit that you've already pushed, you will have to force push instead of regular push.

Presumably the reason it *seemed* like it was timing based, is because you were more likely to amend a commit shortly after committing and pushing a commit you just made a minute ago, whereas working on a new thing and committing that would take more time.

As for *why* amending requires a force push, Git looks at the commit IDs on your branch and the remote branch when determining if a regular push is allowed. If there are commits on the remote that you don't have on your local branch you are trying to push, it will error unless you force push. Every time you amend a commit, you are changing something about the commit and so a new commit ID will be created, meaning the previous one you already pushed is no longer on your branch.

**Tip:** when force pushing, it's a good habit to use:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

instead of the more obvious `git push --force`. The reason is `--force-with-lease` will still error if there are commits on the remote branch that you haven't fetched yet, meaning you (probably) don't know they're there. If you're the only one working on your branch it's unlikely for there to be new commits out there you don't know about, but if you happen to work on the repo from two different machines it could still happen, if for example you push some commits to your branch from work and forget to fetch (or pull) when you get home.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the explanation and clarifies one of the ways git is a mystery to me. (9,999 mysteries to go.) Thank you!

Comment: @Christopher I consider myself an advanced user of Git, and I still learn new things about it, at least once per week. (Maybe because I like to tinker.)

Comment: Thanks again.  Work and home are the same locations, just different machines.

Comment: I was probably confused because the commit is accepted OK and silently sets up the push for failure.

Comment: @Christopher - yeah, anytime you amend or rebase, it's assumed you meant to do it, and if you had already pushed the commits you're re-writing, you'll have to force push next time.